# QML "Do not use 'eval'. (M23)"

Tags: qt, qml

I have 10 checkboxes, which id's are from "cb1" to "cb10". I want to collect their state in list (and then pass it to python). Firstly I came up with very loooong function (every checkbox state was in "if" statement, so function took 30 lines of code or so). I found it awful, so I wrote a "for" loop. But now QtCreator throw me warning from the title. Should I ignore it, or is there prettier way to do it?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var checkedlist: []

    function checkedf() {
        checkedlist = []

        var i = 1
        for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            try {
                checkedlist.push(eval("cb" + i + ".checkState"))
            } catch(error) { }
        }

        console.log(checkedlist)
    }


    CheckBox {
        id: cb1
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb2
        anchors.top: cb1.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb3
        anchors.top: cb2.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb4
        anchors.top: cb3.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb5
        anchors.top: cb4.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb6
        anchors.top: cb5.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb7
        anchors.top: cb6.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb8
        anchors.top: cb7.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb9
        anchors.top: cb8.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: cb10
        anchors.top: cb9.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCheckStateChanged: checkedf()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's reasons `eval` is considered unsafe, but it's not even needed here. Just use a `Repeater`.

```
Column {
    Repeater {
        model: 10

        CheckBox {
            onCheckStateChanged: {
                checkedlist[index] = checkState
            }
        }
    }
}
```